# Ошибка при установке apsw

Tags: python, python-2.x, pip

При попыткe установить модуль `apsw`, `pip` выдает такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более опытные в этом вопросе, помогите

Comment: Не помещайте текстовую информацию в виде картинки. Это может помешать другим людям с похожей проблемой найти данный вопрос. Если не знаете как скопировать текст в консоли, то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip3 search apsw

apsw (3.9.2-r1)            - Another Python SQLite Wrapper
bayeslite-apsw (3.9.2-r1)  - Another Python SQLite Wrapper -- bayeslite custom edition
apsw-cledoux (3.9.2-r1)    - Another Python SQLite Wrapper
```

Напишите просто `pip install apsw`

Comment: Напомню, что я использую python 2.7

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/3v2h0

Comment: Вот что получилось при pip install apsw

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы показали последние строки трейсбека.

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите в директорию с вашим интерпретатором питона и напишите pip install apsw